# How to use a CSS class on all table elements within an application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've realised that I'm going to need to use a css class on all tables within my application.

```
 <table id="tblSearch" class="eFoo-text"
```

The problem is that I've got lots of pages, which contain lots of user controls.

Luckly they all inherit from a single master page. Is there some way to say "use this class on all tables" somewhere in the master page??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your CSS, you can use an element selector.

```
 table{  
  padding:4px;
 }
```

This is apply a padding to ***all*** tables without having to add a class or id to the markup.